Summary results of the 2023 company-run GPT content detection study
I’d like to share with you the summary results of the study on LLM detection we’ve been conducting over the last several months. The study (link only accessible by moderators) was designed to measure how reliably humans can detect AI-generated content in fulfillment of the moderator action agreement. I’m going to present the results in this post, and I will do my best to avoid editorializing on the results and how they should be applied with respect to policy.
A word about the authorship of this study
First, it needs to be said: The researcher from Stack Exchange who was principally responsible for developing and coordinating the study, was let go as part of the October 2023 layoff. It is deeply unfortunate that they are not available to present the results they worked hard to develop - this study took a significant amount of labor to coordinate, and they deserve the vast majority of the credit. On top of this, it puts me in the rather uncomfortable position of presenting results to you that I did not personally develop or analyze. In order to satisfy my own standard of intellectual ethics and integrity, this is what you need to know.
Our researcher completed the vast majority of the analysis before their departure from Stack Exchange. We have retained the raw data, their analytical work, and final internal writeup. The researcher and I discussed their work before their departure. The writeup of their work you are now reading is based heavily on their internal report, but was written by me after their departure.
I have personally done all that I can to verify the accuracy of the results we are presenting, and will faithfully represent both reasonable interpretations and limitations as best I am able. Still, a simple fact needs to be said: The researcher who designed this study has a doctorate in this style of research; I do not. When it comes to analysis of sociological or experimental data, they have many years of training on me. There may be nuances I will miss. The results are important enough to present anyway. If you see errors, do your best to point them out, and I will do my best to correct them with the time, resources, and knowledge I have available to me.
On with the show: Top-line summary
In compliance with one of the negotiated outcomes of the moderator action last year, Stack Exchange conducted a study lasting three weeks with the goal of assessing how effective moderators are at gauging whether content appearing on Stack Overflow is AI-generated. We believe this study to be among the first of its type, analyzing expert opinions on content to determine whether the provenance as human or AI-generated can be reliably determined. Each moderator participating in the survey assessed 20 randomly-selected answers from a pool of 50 total answers: 10 of those assessed were human-authored, and 10 were AI-authored. Responses were collected on a Likert scale, ranging from “Definitely AI-generated” to “Definitely human-generated” to gauge participant confidence.
To create the pool of AI-generated responses, we pulled a random sample of questions from Stack Overflow, pasted the question body into ChatGPT+ (GPT-4) without any additional prompting or text, and copied the response for use in this study. To create the pool of human responses, we employed a sequential mixed sampling method with initial parameters set to exclude responses with images or links, to select only answers within the 500 to 2500 character range, and to select positively-scored and accepted answers from Stack Overflow data. Roughly 10% of answers on Stack Overflow were candidates for selection. We then filtered these responses to identify 'content-rich' examples — those providing explanations rather than mere code or single sentences — in order to create a sample suitable for an in-depth comparison between human and AI-generated responses, which was central to our research objectives. All human answers were pulled directly from the site and pasted into the question draft page on SO to get similar formatting for each, including code blocks. No edits were made.
The AI detection exercise was open for about three weeks. The study had a completion rate of 63% – 48/76 respondents answered all the questions. Four respondents were from moderators on Stack Overflow, three did not specify a site, and 41 were from moderators on other sites on the network.
Across the network, 48 moderators (roughly 10% of all moderators) completed the study. The accuracy of these moderator responses was assessed to be 53%. AI-generated responses were correctly classified around 3-in-10 times; human-generated responses were correctly classified around 7-in-10 times. Moderators were more confident in their assessment of human-generated responses than AI-generated responses (see the second section below). The study suggests that it is more likely a moderator will mark an AI-generated answer as human than the reverse.
Moderator evaluation performance statistics
Moderators were asked to classify answers on a five-point Likert scale, ranging from "definitely human-written" to "definitely AI-generated."
In nearly every classification problem, if one wants to detect a larger quantity of true positives, one needs to accept an increasing quantity of false positives as well. The exact relationship between these two parameters characterizes the performance for a classification method. A classifier performs well when one can detect many true positives, while only allowing for very few false positives.
In order to better express the data from this survey, the results are plotted in such a chart, below. The chart reflects all possible values for the performance of survey respondents - how often respondents detect AI correctly on the bottom axis, and how often respondents detect humans as AI incorrectly on the left axis. In the below chart, the red line represents the performance achieved by respondents during this survey.

If this line is treated as though it represents optimal performance, then it can be used to divide the chart into two regions. The blue region covers every point that would underperform moderators on this survey; the red region, conversely, shows every value would outperform moderators on this survey.
For example, if respondents were to detect 50% of all AI posts correctly, then this chart says respondents would also detect no less than around 20% of human posts incorrectly. This chart therefore provides a rough way to estimate the performance of these responses. As more responses are successfully detected as AI-generated, inevitably more responses will also incorrectly detect human-generated content. This chart shows that moderator performance is better than random chance.
It is important to note that these boundaries should be understood only as rough guides. Error in the survey may result in slightly different placement of the reference points used to construct this chart. Points on or near the boundary should be understood to have considerable uncertainty as a result. Additionally, only a few points on this curve were measured, and control the shape of the curve.



Threshold
True Positives (TP)
False Positives (FP)
TP Rate
FP Rate
TN* Rate
FN Rate




Definitely AI-generated
50
12
10.4%
2.5%
97.5%
89.6%


Likely AI-generated
163
57
34.0%
11.9%
88.1%
66.0%


Not sure
276
137
57.5%
28.5%
71.5%
42.5%


Likely human-written
438
326
91.2%
67.9%
32.1%
8.8%


Definitely human-written
480
480
100.0%
100.0%
0.0%
0.0%



The above table shows the classification statistics of moderator responses, and is the raw data used to construct the above chart. The true positive and false positive counts are reported, as well as statistics about the response rates.
In this study, moderators were presented with 20 randomly-selected answers to evaluate; half were human-written and half were AI-generated. Across all participants, the measured accuracy was:



Answer source
Accuracy
Mean correct
Standard Deviation




All answers
52.7%
10.5
3.6


Human-written
71.5%
7.2
2.2


AI-generated
34.0%
3.4
2.4



The raw counts of moderator responses were as follows:

Moderators assessed human-written content more confidently than AI-generated content
Quoting from our researcher’s internal analysis:

The graphs [above] illustrate that mods were more confident and accurate in identifying human-written content than AI-generated content. Many participants, while leaning towards the right answer, weren't always fully confident in their choices. They were often mistaken and unsure about AI content, resulting in a higher rate of selecting likely human-written content than other categories.

Into the weeds 1: Correct Agreement rates

The “correct agreement rate” is the rate at which responses to each question were correct. It can be clearly seen that humans are much more accurate detectors of human-written text than of AI-generated text; however, only ~25% of the posts were assessed correctly 75% of the time or better.
Into the weeds 2: Total Agreement rates

Total agreement rate is something of a different measure. This reflects the % of moderators who agreed in their evaluation of a question, regardless of whether they were correct. This is much more of a mixed bag: It shows that some AI-authored answers are confidently regarded as human-authored; however, it also shows that confidence in human-authored answers may be lower than expected.
Tentatively, this can be interpreted to mean that the consensus of multiple moderators may not be sufficient to ensure an improvement in accuracy. It shows that it is quite likely one will be able to find multiple moderators who will take either the AI-authored or the human-authored position about most posts on the network. Therefore, finding a few people who agree with one’s own evaluation does not necessarily contribute to the strength of that evaluation.
Limitations of the study

That a conclusion reached in one environment (say the laboratory) will apply in a different environment (say the full-scale process) is based not on statistical reasoning but on what Deming called a “leap of faith.” Good statistics and subject matter knowledge can narrow the chasm but not eliminate it. (Unattributed)

Some limitations of the study need to be acknowledged as part of an effort to understand its applicability. These limitations do not fundamentally invalidate the study, but may affect understanding of its applicability, and the parts of the AI-handling process to which it applies. I will list limitations in no particular order:

The intent of the study was for moderators to gauge answers based on the content of those answers as they appeared in the survey. Exogenous factors, like user age, post creation date, or a user’s history on the site, were not available within the study, and may be used by moderators in practice to evaluate LLM usage.
The method we used to select human-generated answers for the study likely biases in favor of answers that are “better than average” due to positive score and answer acceptance criteria.
Moderators from all sites were asked to assess answers that could be present outside Stack Overflow; therefore, these answers may have been out of the domain of expertise of some respondents. Moderators were asked to indicate their years of coding experience, and no correlation between years of experience and assessment accuracy was found. However, it is known that more than one moderator stopped the survey partway through because they did not have enough experience with software to comfortably assess the answers; selection bias may be present.
The nature of AI answers present on the site has likely changed with time, due to the evolving nature of the technology and changing preconditions of users’ choice to use it. The degree to which the AI-generated answers in this study match typical AI-generated answers on-site is expected to be good, but is fundamentally difficult to assess.
It is theoretically possible for some respondents to have searched for the content of answers using web search tools, and used the existence of the answer on Stack Overflow as a signal to determine authorship. We do not have any evidence to suggest any respondent did this while taking the survey.
Some questions contained code blocks which were not viewable in full within the study. This issue only affected a small number of questions within the study.

Release schedule note
This report was released on the Stack Moderators Team and the Generative AI Heuristics Team on November 7th, 2023. Feedback from these Teams led to a major revision to the primary results section. These revisions are now complete. No further modification or analysis is anticipated.

The response data for this survey is available to download at this link. This dataset contains question IDs, randomized respondent IDs, and randomized respondent order. All demographic data has been removed. This data is released under the Creative Commons 0 (CC0) "No Rights Reserved" license.

The moderator run experiment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/404361/394014

Thanks! Is it possible to share the question-answer pairs that were assessed? (i.e., the SO posts)

@Franck I'm not sure the contents of the Q&A pairs were retained in my copy of the archived data. I'll have to dig a bit to see what I find (assuredly they haven't been completely lost and I'm just personally missing them). Will take a bit more time than I have on hand right now to do.

Great summary. Thanks for conducting the study. Only thing that really surprises me is "We believe this study to be among the first of its type, analyzing expert opinions on content to determine whether the provenance as human or AI-generated can be reliably determined." With all the hype around LLMs I would hope for lots of these Turing test studies to be already conducted, not necessarily focused on programming questions but in general.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Thanks for reading. If I recall correctly, at the time there were some studies regarding lay-audiences' ability to classify AIGC, but there were no reference studies on a cohort that had been exposed to a substantial quantity of AIGC, or on a cohort that had already pursued development of the ability to classify AIGC. Therefore this may be the first study on a cohort that was not intended to represent the general public. It's possible that line is in error, though - I don't think we can reasonably claim to have reviewed every study related to AIGC classification.

@Slate If you ever conduct another such study, it would be nice to include some training phase (showing participants AI/Human generated posts in advance to train them, after all that is something one could also do in real life) before the test. It might also be interesting to compare results to a classification network (trained on different generated Q&A pairs) or a simple feature based (total length, average length of words, other non content features) classifier.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution In theory, most moderators already had a training phase (experience on their sites). In practice, the models were different, so some of the tells were missing; but this in itself shows something. If I re-ran this study today, with a new never-before-seen model, I probably wouldn't include a "training phase" beforehand.

I circulated the information above among multiple groups, including the Stack Moderators Team. Several questions arose with some regularity, and I want to include answers to these here. I want to separate these from the main body of the report, because in order to answer common FAQs, I need to do some work to contextualize the study’s results. I want to ensure that I cleanly separate the presentation of the reults from anything that could be construed as commentary on the results.
I want to clarify up front that I am not quoting any specific moderator in this answer. My primary aim is to capture common questions. Any text that also appears verbatim within the Stack Moderators Team is my own. If you are a moderator who asked one of these questions, and would like attribution for doing so, please let me know and I will include it.
Why was GPT-4 chosen for this study, instead of a LLM in more common usage?
The original researcher picked ChatGPT+ in order to preserve as much validity for future models as possible. As large language model technology is highly likely to improve with time, and access to more capable tools is likely to expand, the researcher's reasoning was that testing on current-iteration technology (i.e. regular ChatGPT) would provide less durable insight than testing on upcoming technology.
While the study may not reflect the specific admixture of LLM versions that are used on the site today, it is more likely to be applicable to future versions of this problem. As with any forward-looking best guess, however, it could be incorrect. This choice obviously has certain limitations that need to be taken into account when considering the current state of the platform.
Why did this study not assess moderator accuracy as it actually is on the site? Why does moderator accuracy depend on how common AI-generated answers are?
Our researcher's primary goal was to produce durable insight into the performance of moderator evaluations of human-authored and AI-generated content. The exact proportion of AI-generated answers on the site is unfortunately not known, and would be challenging to evaluate. Instead, it was necessary to set up a controlled environment where the evaluations could be studied. To apply the results of the study to the network, one needs to know how common AI-generated answers are.
To see why this is the case, suppose moderators act when they feel an answer is "definitely AI-generated." Per the table above, 10.4% of AI-generated answers would be correctly marked as AI-generated ("true positives"), and 2.5% of human-authored answers would be incorrectly marked as AI-authored ("false positives"). However, to assess the precision of moderator evaluations in practice, it is necessary to determine the number of AI-generated and human-authored posts that will be marked AI-generated, not just the percentages. The more AI-generated answers exist on the platform, the more opportunities exist to correctly mark an answer as AI-generated.
To show this more clearly, suppose we were to sample 10,000 posts on a site. Let’s look at three cases:

Of the 10,000 answers in the sample, 1,000 are AI-generated and 9,000 are human-authored.
Of the 10,000 answers in the sample, 5,000 are AI-generated and 5,000 are human-authored.
Of the 10,000 answers in the sample, 9,000 are AI-generated and 1,000 are human-authored (the inverse of case 1 above).

Because the number of AI-generated answer detections depends on how many AI-generated answers there are in the sample, it can be seen in the chart below that as AI-generated answers become more prevalent, the proportion of answers correctly identified as AI-generated will increase.

Since we do not know the exact proportion of AI-generated answers on the site, the study needed to be performed in such a way as to aid future evaluations of this kind. Future work may be able to produce more accurate determinations as to the proportion of answers on Stack Overflow that were generated by AI. These results inform the level of caution that needs to be taken when developing processes and policies to help assess user contributions as potentially AI-generated.
Why did the study not measure whether a moderator would feel comfortable removing an answer?
Approaches to content moderation, and individual moderators' comfort with moderator tools, differ considerably across Stack Exchange, and can even differ strongly from moderator to moderator on the same site. Moderators also have differing levels of overall activity. While it may make sense to ask a moderator individually, or a pool of moderators from one site, to rate whether the answer would be deleted, generalizing these results to all sites would not necessarily be informative as to the composition of answers that would actually be deleted in practice.
